# Google Maps API - what is the meaning/function of this line?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm adding a search box to my Google Map. From the documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox):

```
// Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
```

I'm trying to understand exactly how this works on a low level. **What does the last line do?** If it links the search box to the UI element as the comments say, how does it do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomExample

```
// Add the control to the map at a designated control position
// by pushing it on the position's array. This code will
// implicitly add the control to the DOM, through the Map
// object. You should not attach the control manually.
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(controlDiv);
```